# Extending the "Add Media"-Dialog ... how do I finally insert something to the Post?

Tags: plugins, media, tinymce, visual-editor, post-editor

I'm developing a plugin, which extends the "add media"-Button in the Post-Editor.

I found an example (I think it was nextGen Galley maybe) where wp_iframe is used in the add media dialog. For some reasons it was quite comfortable to build my stuff the same way.

This is how id I did it:

```
// add entry to "add media" menu
add_filter('media_upload_tabs', function($tabs) {
    return array_merge($tabs, array('jt' => "jt's plugin"));
});

// my own "add media" page
add_action('media_upload_jt', function() {

    // use plugin stylesheet
    add_action('admin_print_styles-media-upload-popup', function() {
        $cssUrl = plugins_url() .'/jt.css';
        wp_enqueue_style('jt_mediamenu', $cssUrl);
    });
    return wp_iframe('media_jt_dialogue'); 
});


function media_jt_dialogue() {

        /* do some interactive stuff using the iframe 
         * and forms like a boss (not using ajax and pretending it's still 2005)
         */

        /* yeah... and now? */
}
```

But I don't know what to do next and can't figure it out. I want to return the result of the dialog with the user in the iframe to tinyMCE editor now (in form of a shortcode maybe). But how? I think I've to trigger some Javascript, but I'm sure Wordpress holds a clean default solution for that. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself. I had to call

```
media_upload_header();
```

in the Iframe and trigger the following javascript:

```
var html = 'stuff I want to return to editor';
var win = window.dialogArguments || opener || parent || top;
win.send_to_editor(html);
```

I have no Idea how, but this works.